# RSpec controller spec is acting like a request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

- Rails 5.0.0.rc1
- rspec-core@a99ff26
- rspec-rails@052206f

I have a controller spec that looks roughly like this:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe InquiriesController, type: :controller do
  describe "#create" do
    let(:inquiry_attributes) { attributes_for(:inquiry) }

    before do
      post :create, inquiry: inquiry_attributes
    end

    it "whatever" do
      expect(2).to be 2
    end
  end
end
```

This lives in **spec/controllers/inquiries_controller_spec.rb**, so RSpec should not be inferring that it's a request spec based on its location.

When I run this spec, I get the following error:

```
1) InquiriesController#create whatever
   Failure/Error: post :create, inquiry: inquiry_attributes

   URI::InvalidURIError:
     bad URI(is not URI?): create
     # /Users/spetryk/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:193:in `env_for'
     # /Users/spetryk/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:66:in `post'
```

Hmm, it seems that `post` is coming from Rack. Not sure why. Here's my spec_helper and rails_helper:

**spec_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.filter_run focus: true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

require "spec_helper"
require "rspec/rails"
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # Yes, I've tried removing this line
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

My InquiriesController lives in **app/controllers/inquiries_controller.rb**, is not underneath a module, and the route is wired up correctly (I verified this by manually visiting it and verifying that it works). The method is indeed named `create` and I've done this successfully with other projects.

Comment: It might be worth noting that changing `:create` to `/inquiries` makes the spec pass.

Comment: You can accept your own answer after 48 hours. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @HolgerJust I know, but I wanted to avoid people wasting their time looking at this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was happening. I had mindlessly copied a company-standard `spec_helper` that included `Rack::Test::Methods`, injecting the Rack methods into all of my tests.